# calling function of one class from another not valid constructor arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, constructor, call

I am trying to call the class function from another aspx page. But when I try to initialize the class getting the error.

Previously also I tried calling this class from another aspx page, got similar type of issues. And from that page, visual studio generated the constructor.

```
// my class
public class ClsProcessOrders
{ 

    public ClsProcessOrders(OrderPTO orderPTO_Ally)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.orderPTO_Ally = orderPTO_Ally;
    }

    public void InputRecord ()
    {
        // logic
    }
    public class OrderPTO
    {
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }  
        public string OrderName { get; set; }
        public string OrderAddr { get; set; }        
        public string OrderTel { get; set; }
        public string OrderMobile { get; set; } 
        public string OrderAccIdNo { get; set; }  
        public string OrderDate { get; set; }  
        public string OrderAgent { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

My aspx page code is ::

```
if (orderGenerate == 1 && lbl_agent_name.Text == "willis")
{   // not getting error here
    ClsProcessOrders.OrderPTO obj = new ClsProcessOrders.OrderPTO()
    {                           
        OrderNumber = orderNum,
        OrderName = orderName,                                                                               
        OrderAccIdNo = orderAcc;
    };
    // getting error here
    ClsProcessOrders objWillis = new ClsProcessOrders();   
}
```

When I do `ClsProcessOrders objWillis = new ClsProcessOrders();`  getting error :: **doesnot contain constructor that takes 0 arguments**.

Also I tried `ClsProcessOrders objWillis = new ClsProcessOrders(ClsProcessOrders.OrderPTO obj);` :: gives error **ClsProcessOrders.OrderPTO is a  'type', which is not valid in the given context**.

As the suggestions, I tried doing `ClsProcessOrders objWillis = new ClsProcessOrders(obj)` gives error:: **the name 'obj' does not exists in the current context**.

How to call the function **InputRecord** from this aspx page?

Comment: of course, your class do not define a` default parameterless constructor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ClsProcessOrders.OrderPTO is a 'type', which is not valid in the given
>   context.

You have defined the class `OrderPTO` inside the class `ClsProcessOrders` take it outside the class.

> Doesnot contain constructor that takes 0 arguments.

For parameter less constructor make a constructor without parameter.

```
public ClsProcessOrders()
{

}
```

And if you want to pass parameter than do this

```
ClsProcessOrders objWillis = new ClsProcessOrders(obj);
```

You can call `InputRecord` by making object of `ClsProcessOrders` like this

```
ClsProcessOrders objWillis = new ClsProcessOrders(obj);  
objWillis.InputRecord();
```

**Note**

> If you want a function to be called outside from its class you need to make it `public`.You have made `InputRecord` private change it to `public`.

Comment: I can not do that. this class `ClsProcessOrders` was written previously. I can not change this one. I have to make changes in my aspx page

Comment: This won't make any difference.

Comment: I am getting the error and edited the question. Please look into it.

Comment: my issue is to **call the function** `InputRecord` from the aspx page. how can I do this? please suggest.

Comment: thanks but does not make any changes. I made the function public, but also can not access the function.

Comment: my actual problem was OrderAccIdNo = orderAcc;

Answer (score 1):

You defined the constructor of ClsProcessOrders in this way:

```
public ClsProcessOrders(OrderPTO orderPTO_Ally)
```

That means you have to pass a object with type OrderPTO to constuctor but you call it without an object:

```
ClsProcessOrders objWillis = new ClsProcessOrders();
```

use

```
ClsProcessOrders objWillis = new ClsProcessOrders(obj);
```

instead.

Comment: please make modification in objects name objWillis. Sorry for this!